# Slow Load Times

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I am having issues with page load times on a Wordpress site I run. On it, users join to watch live content so that means at specific times I can have 500-1000 people logging on all at once.

The pages are relatively small, 2-3MB. All the video content is hosted on a CDN like Vimeo and I use iFrames to show it. The server is oversized. Load averages never get over 10, CPU/Memory/disk i/o all 70-80% capacity free. The server has 64 GB of memory and 32 vCPUs with well over 1Gbps. All hosted on Digitial Ocean.

MYSQL, via MYTOP, has 100% Efficiency. Even with all this, load times still get really long when all the demand comes in.

I know I can do better with caching but what else am I missing?

```
Specs 
== Server Environment ==
 Operating System: Linux
 Software: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
 MySQL version: MySQL Community Server - GPL v8.0.19
 PHP Version: 7.4.3
 PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
 PHP Max Post Size: 16M
 GD Installed: Yes
 ZIP Installed: Yes
 Write Permissions: All right
 Elementor Library: Connected

== Wordpress ==
Version:5.4.2 
Max Upload Size:16 MB
Memory limit:512M
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.